# How to display middle dots in scatterplot in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to show the middle gray dots as in this figure, I circled the gray dots in red, when I'm plotting my data, these gray dots don't show:

[image]

I tried different things including:

```
ggplot(fig5cwithoutdesc,
       aes(a_donor, correlation, color=(geneIDs %in% idza)))
```

This is the head of dput with dropleveled data:

```
structure(list(geneIDs = c("PCSK1N", "BCAM", "RPLP1", "RPL18", 
"BSG", "RPL37"), a_cell = c(0.847, 0.823, 0.821, 0.804, 0.789, 
0.789), a_donor = c(0.644, 0.717, 0.723, 0.716, 0.669, 0.713), 
    geneIDs.1 = structure(c(3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 5L), .Label = c("'C1QL1'", 
    "'INS'", "'PCSK1N'", "'SNHG7'", "'TMEM259'", "'ZSCAN18'"), class = "factor"), 
    b_cell = c(0.858, 0.796, 0.76, 0.738, 0.737, 0.733), b_donor = c(0.644, 
    0.662, 0.547, 0.185, 0.568, 0.617), geneIDs.2 = structure(c(6L, 
    2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L), .Label = c("'ALDOA'", "'CTSD'", "'NPDC1'", 
    "'PCSK1N'", "'PTP4A3'", "'RPLP1'"), class = "factor"), g_cell = c(0.81, 
    0.761, 0.722, 0.717, 0.655, 0.655), g_donor = c(0.723, 0.657, 
    0.613, 0.644, 0.321, 0.363), geneIDs.3 = structure(c(4L, 
    3L, 2L, 6L, 5L, 1L), .Label = c("'CALY'", "'CDK5R2'", "'CELF3'", 
    "'PCSK1N'", "'PODXL2'", "'TPGS1'"), class = "factor"), d_cell = c(0.751, 
    0.723, 0.715, 0.706, 0.701, 0.687), d_donor = c(0.644, 0.587, 
    0.573, 0.626, 0.629, 0.58), geneIDs.4 = structure(c(5L, 2L, 
    3L, 1L, 4L, 6L), .Label = c("'ACAP3'", "'AP1S1'", "'JUND'", 
    "'OGFR'", "'RPL7A'", "'STK11'"), class = "factor"), acinar_cell = c(0.776, 
    0.775, 0.766, 0.715, 0.702, 0.694), acinar_donor = c(0.64, 
    0.683, 0.46, 0.559, 0.439, 0.527), geneIDs.5 = structure(c(2L, 
    4L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 6L), .Label = c("'CD151'", "'EEF2'", "'HLA-A'", 
    "'PPDPF'", "'PRSS22'", "'TAF10'"), class = "factor"), ductal_cell = c(0.855, 
    0.854, 0.842, 0.837, 0.834, 0.833), ductal_donor = c(0.774, 
    0.773, 0.447, 0.615, 0.486, 0.69), rank = 1:6, geneIDs.6 = structure(c(5L, 
    1L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 4L), .Label = c("'EEF2'", "'FKBP8'", "'PPDPF'", 
    "'RPL8'", "'RPLP2'", "'RPS15'"), class = "factor"), correlation = c(0.8, 
    0.77, 0.77, 0.77, 0.77, 0.75), p.value = c(1.08e-191, 2.43e-173, 
    2.6e-173, 5.24e-172, 1.92e-170, 1.61e-156), adj.p.value = c(2.16e-186, 
    1.73e-168, 1.73e-168, 2.62e-167, 7.68e-166, 5.38e-152), RefSeq = c(34347L, 
    398136L, 227653L, 586047L, 992661L, 198984L), RPKM = c(3028L, 
    3081L, 4336L, 5384L, 3404L, 5346L)), row.names = c(NA, 6L
), class = "data.frame")
```

But it seems that I'm missing something,
This is my code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)
library(dplyr)

fig5cwithoutdesc <- read.csv(url("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/learnseq/learning/main/fig5cwithoutdesc3.txt"),sep = '\t',header = TRUE)

fig5cwithoutdesc$geneIDs <- trimws(gsub('[[:punct:] ]+',' ',fig5cwithoutdesc$geneIDs))

idza <- c("RPL31", "HSPB1", "MAFB", "ALPL1", "VGF","PCSK1N", "BSG", "CALY", "B2M", "SCG5", "TM4SF4")

plain <- function(x,...) {
  format(x, ..., scientific = FALSE, drop0trailing = TRUE)
}
theme01 <- theme_bw()+ theme(axis.title=element_text(size=18,face="plain"), legend.position = 'none', panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), axis.text.x = element_text(size=12, colour = "black", margin = unit(c(3, 0, 0, 0), "mm")), axis.text.y = element_text(size=12, colour = "black", margin = unit(c(0, 3, 0, 0), "mm")), axis.title.x = element_text(margin = margin(t = 12, r = 0, b = 0, l = 0)), axis.ticks.length=unit(-0.1, "cm"), plot.margin = unit(c(2,2,2,2), "lines"), panel.border = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line())

library(repr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
options(repr.plot.width=6, repr.plot.height=4)

#Plot scatterplot by each cell type
zaal <- ggplot(fig5cwithoutdesc,
       aes(a_donor, a_cell, color=(geneIDs %in% idza)))+
  geom_point()+
  scale_color_manual(values = c('gray','royalblue1')) +
  geom_text_repel(data=subset(fig5cwithoutdesc,geneIDs %in% idza),
                  aes(x=a_donor, y=a_cell,label=geneIDs, 
                      force=10), 
                 color='black',
                  segment.size  = 0.2,
                  segment.color = "grey50", 
                  direction     = "y", 
                  hjust         = 1) + 

  xlab(expression("Spearman's" ~ rho* ", all cells")) +
  ylab("Spearman's" ~ rho* ", "*alpha*"-cells") + 
  
    
#assign proper breaks as in the figure    
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(-1, 1, by = 0.2), limits=c(-1,1), expand = c(0,0), labels=plain)+ 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(-1, 1, by = 0.2), limits=c(-1,1), expand = c(0,0), labels=plain)+
  theme01

zaal
```

However; I'm gettting this plot without the middle dots:

[image]

Comment: What is the group name for those gray dots, and does it appear in both `geneIDs` and `idza`?

Comment: The plot should alpha cell group vs all cells (correlation column), but when I tried it, it did not work @Dylan_Gomes

Comment: You didn't actually answer my questions. I am not seeing any code for scaling alpha here, just color.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to look for a method for imputation those missing values. Here, I will include a very basic method but you can further explore other ways:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)
library(dplyr)

fig5cwithoutdesc <- read.csv(url("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/learnseq/learning/main/fig5cwithoutdesc3.txt"),sep = '\t',header = TRUE)

fig5cwithoutdesc$geneIDs <- trimws(gsub('[[:punct:] ]+',' ',fig5cwithoutdesc$geneIDs))

idza <- c("RPL31", "HSPB1", "MAFB", "ALPL1", "VGF","PCSK1N", "BSG", "CALY", "B2M", "SCG5", "TM4SF4")

plain <- function(x,...) {
  format(x, ..., scientific = FALSE, drop0trailing = TRUE)
}
theme01 <- theme_bw()+ theme(axis.title=element_text(size=18,face="plain"), legend.position = 'none', panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), axis.text.x = element_text(size=12, colour = "black", margin = unit(c(3, 0, 0, 0), "mm")), axis.text.y = element_text(size=12, colour = "black", margin = unit(c(0, 3, 0, 0), "mm")), axis.title.x = element_text(margin = margin(t = 12, r = 0, b = 0, l = 0)), axis.ticks.length=unit(-0.1, "cm"), plot.margin = unit(c(2,2,2,2), "lines"), panel.border = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line())
#Values
i1 <- seq(-0.4,0.4,by=0.1)
#lm model
mod <- lm(a_donor~a_cell,data=fig5cwithoutdesc)
pred <- predict(mod,data.frame(a_cell=i1))
#Create random values to impute
fig5cwithoutdesc$a_donor[is.na(fig5cwithoutdesc$a_donor)] <-
  sample(i1,length(which(is.na(fig5cwithoutdesc$a_donor))),replace = T)
fig5cwithoutdesc$a_cell[is.na(fig5cwithoutdesc$a_cell)] <-
  sample(pred,length(which(is.na(fig5cwithoutdesc$a_cell))),replace = T)

#Plot scatterplot by each cell type
ggplot(fig5cwithoutdesc,
               aes(a_donor, a_cell, color=(geneIDs %in% idza)))+
  geom_point()+
  scale_color_manual(values = c('gray','royalblue1')) +
  geom_text_repel(data=subset(fig5cwithoutdesc,geneIDs %in% idza),
                  aes(x=a_donor, y=a_cell,label=geneIDs, 
                      force=10), 
                  color='black',
                  segment.size  = 0.2,
                  segment.color = "grey50", 
                  direction     = "y", 
                  hjust         = 1) + 
  
  xlab(expression("Spearman's" ~ rho* ", all cells")) +
  ylab("Spearman's" ~ rho* ", "*alpha*"-cells") + 
  
  
  #assign proper breaks as in the figure    
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(-1, 1, by = 0.2), limits=c(-1,1), expand = c(0,0), labels=plain)+ 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(-1, 1, by = 0.2), limits=c(-1,1), expand = c(0,0), labels=plain)+
  theme01
```

Output:

[image]

Some points are duplicated that is why you get a grid. Exploring other ways will enable to complete the data properly.

Comment: Thank you so much @Duck!, can we open chat room?

Comment: @user432797 Sure!